# Where can I change the settings for UV unwrap?

Tags: interface, uv

*Angle based* and *Conformal* for Blender 2.69? Are these still there?

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

When you unwrap, at the bottom of the Tool Shelf accessed by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> or press <kbd>F6</kbd> to bring up the popup.